# Webpack - Inject bundle file to existing html file

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

Using html-webpack-plugin with web pack,

- Can create or generate a index.html file
- Can use template to generate a index.html file

But I want to inject the bundled JS and CSS file to another existing html file.
I didn't find any options to do that in the plugin.

We have Asp.net MVC _layout.html.
If I go with the template option, the contents from _layout.html are broken since more code in _Layout.html are html mixed with c#.

Do we have any option to replace content without breaking or add bundled file to existing html file?

Answer (score 0):

Set your html file as template.
template: 'path / to / template / index.html'
Your template extends the basic plugin template.
You can freely modify the template, which is defacto your file e.g. index.html modified by the plugin.